# Combine two scripts

Tags: powershell

I'm using one script to call another I would like to combine the two. I'm creating a GUI to house a few tools that I would use to help me learn PS. I bought PowerShell Studio and got things working the way I want in commandline but now I want the GUI part. I dont like that I use one script to call another.

```
$form1_Load={
#TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
}

$buttonGetInventory_Click= {
#TODO: Place custom script here
$scriptlocation = "C:\temp\System_Inventory\System_Inventory.ps1"
$Computers = $textbox1.Text

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -FilePath $scriptlocation -ComputerName $Computer - Verbose
    $filename = "$computer" + ".html"
    #$filename = "khonemdczdc03.html"
    $htmlpath = "\\$computer\c$\windows\temp\$filename"
    $uncpath =  "\\uncpath\citrix\Documentation\Citrix\Inventory\$filename"
    Copy-Item $htmlpath $uncpath

}
$labelStatus.Text = "Complete"
}



<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Windows Machine Inventory Using PowerShell.

.DESCRIPTION
    This script is to document the Windows machine. This script will work only for Local Machine.

.EXAMPLE
    PS C:\> .\System_Inventory.PS1

.OUTPUTS
    HTML File OutPut ReportDate , General Information , BIOS Information etc.

#>

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$UserName = (Get-Item  env:\username).Value 
$ComputerName = (Get-Item env:\Computername).Value
#$filepath = (Get-ChildItem env:\userprofile).value
$filepath = "c:\windows\temp"


Add-Content  "$Filepath\style.CSS"  -Value " body {
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:10pt;
background-image:url('C:\Images\CookieAuth.jpg'); 
}
th { 
background-color:black;

color:white;
}
td {
background-color:#19fff0;
color:black;
}"

Write-Host "CSS File Created Successfully... Executing Inventory Report!!!     Please Wait !!!" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
#ReportDate
$ReportDate = Get-Date | Select -Property DateTime |ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

 #General Information
$ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | 
Select -Property Model , Manufacturer , Description , PrimaryOwnerName ,    SystemType |ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#Boot Configuration
$BootConfiguration = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BootConfiguration |
Select -Property Name , ConfigurationPath | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment 

#BIOS Information
$BIOS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS | Select -Property PSComputerName ,    Manufacturer , Version | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#Operating System Information
$OS = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select -Property Caption , CSDVersion , OSArchitecture , OSLanguage | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#Time Zone Information
$TimeZone = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_TimeZone | Select Caption , StandardName |
ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#Logical Disk Information
$Disk = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter DriveType=3 | 
Select SystemName , DeviceID , @{Name=”size(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -   f($_.size/1gb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” - f($_.freespace/1gb)}} |
ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#CPU Information
$SystemProcessor = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor  | 
 Select SystemName , Name , MaxClockSpeed , Manufacturer , status  |ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#Memory Information
$PhysicalMemory = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PhysicalMemory |
Select -Property Tag , SerialNumber , PartNumber , Manufacturer ,  DeviceLocator , @{Name="Capacity(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f  ($_.Capacity/1GB)}} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment

#Software Inventory
$Software = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |
Select Name , Vendor , Version , Caption | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment 

ConvertTo-Html -Body "<font color = blue><H4><B>Report Executed On</B></H4>   </font>$ReportDate
<font color = blue><H4><B>General Information</B></H4></font>$ComputerSystem
<font color = blue><H4><B>Boot Configuration</B></H4>  </font>$BootConfiguration
<font color = blue><H4><B>BIOS Information</B></H4></font>$BIOS
<font color = blue><H4><B>Operating System Information</B></H4></font>$OS
<font color = blue><H4><B>Time Zone Information</B></H4></font>$TimeZone
<font color = blue><H4><B>Disk Information</B></H4></font>$Disk
<font color = blue><H4><B>Processor Information</B></H4> </font>$SystemProcessor
<font color = blue><H4><B>Memory Information</B></H4></font>$PhysicalMemory
<font color = blue><H4><B>Software Inventory</B></H4></font>$Software" -  CssUri  "$filepath\style.CSS" -Title "Server Inventory" | Out-File  "$FilePath\$ComputerName.html"

Write-Host "Script Execution Completed" -ForegroundColor Yellow

Invoke-Item -Path "$FilePath\$ComputerName.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question:**

Just Copy & Paste the code you need into a function at your script.
See [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx) on how to use Functions in PowerShell.

```
Function SystemInventory([String]$ComputerName) {
    Do-Something-With-The-Computer
    Write-Host "Some string"
    return $SomeVar
}
```

Keep in mind that this is only an example. PowerShell supports many more syntaxes for this.

---

**To give you a tip:**

If your script goes bigger, it makes much more sense to leave the function in another file and import it at runtime (not in the loop) with `. '.\System_Inventory.ps1'`

Comment: But then the files need to be available, and not on a network drive because of the double hop issue.

Comment: Sure. The script file in my example has to be in the same directory. You can put them also on a network drive. The double hop issue depends on your use case.